# Is there something like follow-fork-mode for gdbserver?

Tags: gdb

My question is quite straight forward: is there a possibility to tell gdbserver to follow the child when forking like

```
set follow-fork-mode child
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems to be not supported (a bug?). See this [bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13584) in `gdb` bugzilla.

I am not aware of any recent update concerning this bug...

Comment: So, is there any chance to do usable remote debugging with IDA? :-)

Comment: If the bug is fixed one day, it will be perfectly usable. But, waiting for this, it's quite doubtful. Anyway, posting your question here can put some more pressure on the `gdb` dev team ! ;-)

Comment: GDB is open source. *HINT* :)

Comment: I agree with @Devolus ! Go, go, go ! :)

Comment: I didn't try, but the last comments in the bug report claim that this was fixed in 2015.